# Meteor Phonegap/Cordova integration developing Apps different from the WebApp

Tags: javascript, mongodb, cordova, meteor, user-experience

For a project I am utilizing Meteor and since I also need Android and iOS apps, I was looking into and forward to the integration of Cordova into the core.

What I am still uncertain about is to find a way of creating a whole webservice with the best user experience and for that the smartphone-apps would differ substantially from the WebApp (but still have classes, collections etc in common).
I think there is still something missing like a /cordova or /mobile folder but how can I avoid having many "if (Meteor.isCordova)" statements in my code? Also the smartphone code would be visible in the WebApp, which I just don't find good coding style.

The only solutions I see is to either

- make heavy use of the api.addFiles( [] , 'web.cordova') or
- have two completely separate Meteor-Apps (2x "$meteor create"), one for the browser, one for cordova.

So my question is whether in the above second case it is possible to connect two different running apps to the same mongoDB and if so how?

E.g. is there a caching that comes in the way.

Regards

Comment: you are right, there should be a special rule for including certain files only on Cordova or only for browsers. We didn't build that yet but plan to do so in the future.

Comment: Thank you anyway. I guess we just have to be patient.